# Byte[ ] too large to convert to System.Drawing.Image?

Tags: c#, arrays, image, converters, pdfsharp

I'm trying to save an `Image` from a `Byte[]`, and I keep getting kicked out with `ArgumentException : Parameter is not valid`.  I'm wondering if the `Byte[]` is too large to convert.  Is there a limit?

### Code:

```
private XImage[] GetImagesFromURL(List<string> lstCutSheetURLs)
{
    int itr = lstCutSheetURLs.Count;
    XImage[] m_imgCutSheets = new XImage[itr];

    using (var webClient = new WebClient())
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < itr; i++)
        {
            var imageBytes = webClient.DownloadData(lstCutSheetURLs[i]);
            if (imageBytes != null && imageBytes.Length > 0)
            {
                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
                ImageConverter converter = new ImageConverter();

                //
                //THIS IS WHERE IT BREAKS EVERY TIME
                Image img = (Image)converter.ConvertFrom(imageBytes);
                //

                img.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
                m_imgCutSheets[i] = XImage.FromStream(ms);
            }
        }
    }

    return m_imgCutSheets;
}
```

The `Byte[]` ends up holding 458,330 indexes.  Is that way too many?  Is there a better way to get images from websites?  I've been looking all over trying to find things out, and now I'm here.

Any articles / advice / answers are greatly appreciated!  Thanks.

Comment: Does this work with smaller images?

Comment: What line is throwing the error

Comment: @Trey Below this line: `//THIS IS WHERE IT BREAKS EVERY TIME`.

Comment: @rhughes - I don't know.  My Task is to pull images from websites, so all the source is set up to do and work around that.  Haven't tried with any other images.  Rather, I should say that I'm only working with one particular image from one particular website during testing.

Comment: Can you try with other images to confirm whether the problem is the image itself, the size of the image or something else?

Comment: Here's an easy image, the Microsoft logo: https://assets.onestore.ms/cdnfiles/external/uhf/long/9a49a7e9d8e881327e81b9eb43dabc01de70a9bb/images/microsoft-gray.png

Comment: The Microsoft one worked fine.  One possible factor is obviously size.  It came out to just over 4k indexes - 1/100 of the other.  The other factor may be that the Microsoft image was a `.png` file, whereas my program will be looking for `.pdf`'s...  I'll need to check other, smaller `.pdf`'s from online to see if it's an array size thing - or just a problem with the particular one I was working on.

Comment: Well I do feel like a dumb ass now :-)

Comment: Well here's a dummy PDF with a small size: http://hypergrid.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/dummyPDF.pdf

Comment: Hold on, wait a sec, you're throwing the byte[] of a PDF at ImageConverter, correct?

Comment: Building off of @equalsk's comment, you should probably use the [`helper functions`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imageconverter(v=vs.110).aspx) `CanConvertFrom` and `CanConvertTo` to verify the converter supports the formats you are working with before actually calling `ConvertFrom`.

Comment: @Equalsk - Correct.  That's the idea.  Manufacturers obviously place `.pdf`'s online of their merchandise.  I'm trying to retrieve that from online, and create a local copy.  Catch - I do this from multiple manufacturers at a time, so the end goal is to (potentially) grab several `.pdf`'s from online, and Append them to a single `.pdf`.  It's a huge pain in the ass

Comment: I agree to some extent.  I think it has less to do with the fact that it's coming from a `.pdf` than it does the number of indices in the array.  If I can convert a `.png` to a `byte[]` and then the `byte[]` to an `Image`, there shouldn't be a difference if the `byte[]` is formed from a `.pdf`.  When getting the test `.pdf` from online, it's populates the array just fine, but it's 458,330 indices...

Comment: Given that you download the whole PDF to then convert it to an image, I assume this is simply a matter of local storage rather than bandwidth?

Comment: Correct.  Bandwidth is not a factor at all.  I don't think the local storage is either at this point.  I'm not trying to place a 20gb `.pdf` in the memory.  I'm going to try with a couple different image types to try to get to the bottom of this...

Comment: Well, pdf is a complicated format that the `ImageConverter` would have to know how to render into an `Image`. Judging from your comments it apparently can do this, but it doesn't mean it will support *tomorrow's* version of PDF that is possibly entirely different despite having a `.pdf` extension. Also, I can also rename a `.exe` to `.png` and upload it to your site, or even upload an unknowingly corrupted file -- that's why I would use `CanConvertFrom` to verify your `byte`'s actually form a known image format and aren't just garbage (to the converter).

Comment: Oh.  Didn't know that function did that.  Thanks Q

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PDF files are vector files. It seems that the `ImageConverter` class cannot handle PDF files (judging from your self-answer; PDF files are much more than images and it makes sense that ImageConverter does not try to convert them). If it could, it would still fundamentally change the PDF content from vector to raster, losing the scalability and possibly leading to larger files.

The best you can do to add pages from one PDF file to another is using the `XPdfForm` class. You can use the form object in calls to `DrawImage` like you draw raster images to PDF.

Code snippet:
`XPdfForm form = XPdfForm.FromFile(filename);`

Sample code on the PDFsharp site:
http://pdfsharp.net/wiki/TwoPagesOnOne-sample.ashx

JPG files are another special case your code should take care of. Converting JPG to PNG is possible, but makes no sense. PNG is a lossless format, JPG has losses but drastically reduces the file size. Converting from JPG to PNG leads in most cases to a larger file with JPEG artefacts.

IMHO it is OK to use `ImageConverter` for other types beside PDF and JPG. It could be a good validation to see whether files are complete.
Since `XImage.FromStream` can handle several image formats (PNG, BMP, GIF, TIFF, JPG), this may not really add functionality beside the validation.

While this does not really answer the question in your title, this is general advice on PDFsharp image handling/PDF image handling and you asked for related advice in your question.

Answer (score 0):

As is turns out, there is (at least not as far as my tests went) a limit to how many indices the `ImageConverter` will process to create a `System.Drawing.Image`.

However, there doesn't seem to be formatting restrictions.  I was trying to retrieve `.pdf` files from online, store them in my `byte[]`, and then place them in the `Image` variable.  Though I was successful in retrieving the `.pdf`, the converter doesn't seem to recognize the format of the contents of the array.

Notes:

1. The original **`.pdf`** I retrieved created an array with **458,330
   indices** and would not process through the converter.
2. The **`.png`** I retrieved created an array with **4,054 indices** and
       processed correctly.
3. A second **`.pdf`** was then used, creating an array with **7,945 indices**,
       and would not process through the converter.
4. Finally, a **`.jpg`** was used, creating an array with **2,769,747
       indices**, and *processed correctly*.

Because of these results, I believe that the problem lies in the file type being utilized - not the size of the file.

I have not found a solution to this problem yet, but when I do, I will edit this answer to reflect it for reference to those in need.